# Post запрос с данными в форму библиотекой Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup, парсер

**Задача**: передать данные на сайт, а именно: отправить сообщение пользователю.

**Пример**: авторизация с последующим переходом на страницу для парсинга данных под пользователем:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://адрес/user/login")
    .data("email", edt_email.getText().toString())
    .data("pass", edt_pass.getText().toString())
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();
Document doc = res.parse();
sessionId = res.cookie("bffssu");
Log.i("idSession", sessionId.toString());
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://адрес")
    .userAgent("Mozzila")
    .cookie("bffssu", sessionId)
    .get();
el_get_trulyalya = doc2.select("div.j-list");
```

Далее: нужно отправить сообщение пользователю. Форма отправки сообщения в html:

```
<form class="i-imailDialog-form form bff_ajax_iframe_inited" method="POST" action="http://адрес/user/messages?i=vadumo" id="j-my-chat-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="bff_ajax_iframe226">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="send">
    <input type="hidden" name="i" value="vadumo">

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Отправить</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880">
    <input type="file" name="attach" class="j-upload-file hidden">

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right j-upload-file-btn">Прикрепить файл</button>
    <div class="pull-right j-file-name hidden">
        <span class="j-name"></span> <a href="#" class="link-delete j-upload-delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="help-block text-right mrgb0">Максимальный размер файла - 5 МБ</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="4ee5104221f47408cd"></form>
```

Comment: отправляете POST запросс на `http://адрес/user/messages?i=vadumo`. Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я и отправляю методом postDocument doc;
  try{
   
   doc = Jsoup.connect("http://адресс/user/messages/chat?user=vadumo")
       .userAgent("Mozilla")
       .cookie("bffssu", str_cookies)
       .data("message","Test")
       .data("act","send")
       .post();
   el = doc.select("html");
   for(Element el: el){
    Log.i("Elements", el.text());
   }

  }
  catch(IOException e){
   Log.i("IOExeption", "error");
  }
  catch(RuntimeException e){
   Log.i("RuntimeException", "error");
  }

Comment: мало полей. В форме намного больше, чем 2 поля.

Comment: data("message", "Test") -сообщение ,а data("act", "send") - кнопка но мне бросает исключение RuntimeExeption

Comment: так выложите сюда стактрейс исключения

Comment: Мне нужно только заполнить поле с текстом и обработать нажатие кнопки, а остальные пока ненужно!

Comment: если вам ненужно, это не значит, что сайту тоже ненужно. Выложите для начала стактрейс ошибки

Comment: От ошибки избавился, видимо была проблема с инетом просто! Но сообщение по прежнему не передает! Ничего просто напросто не происходит при клике отправить: doc = Jsoup.connect("http://адрес/user/messages/chat?user=vadumo")
               .userAgent("Mozilla")
               .data("message","Test")
               .data("i","vadumo")
               .data("act","send")
               .cookie("bffssu", str_cookies)
               .post();

Comment: Как я уже 2 раза написал выше, добавьте все параметры, которые присутствуют в форме, кроме, возможно, файла.

Comment: Не может ли быть проблема в использовании разных адресов: `http://адрес/user/messages?i=vadumo` и `http://адрес/user/messages/chat?user=vadumo` ?

Comment: Добавил выше описан input, textarea может я что то упустил?!

Comment: Pavel Parshin - о точно возможно из за этого... не обратил внимание, сейчас проверю!

Comment: @Jekman, если у вас получилось решить задачу, то выложите её решение в ответе - это поможет будущим посетителям страницы.

Comment: Проблема так и не решена, как только что то получится я обязательно напишу ответ!

Comment: Если уже есть решение, опубликуйте его как ответ.

Comment: Jekman, опубликуйте пожалуйста решение. С подобным столкнулся, но пока результата нет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно серверная сторона явно ожидает multipart. Отправить запрос в данном режиме без отправки самого файла можно следующим образом

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://адрес/user/messages?i=vadumo")
        .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .data("message","Test")
        .post();
```